# Factory pattern to instance sorters safe for multi-threading?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, factory-pattern

First is this a **good** factory pattern?  *Update: no - ISorter does not technically fit the correct definition for a factory pattern*
Given the following interface:

```
public interface ISorter
{
    ISorter Initialize(IEnumerable<int> Source);
    void Sort( );

    string Name { get; }
    IEnumerable<int> SortedList { get; }
}
```

...and 3 sorters - InsertionSort, MergeSort, and QuickSort. Here is an implementation using MergeSort:

```
[Export(typeof(ISorter))]
public class MergeSorter : ISorter
{
    int[] leftArray;
    int[] rightArray;

    private MergeSorter(IEnumerable<int> source)
    {
        //  independent copies of array
        leftArray = source.ToArray( );
        rightArray = source.ToArray( );
    }

    public ISorter Initialize(IEnumerable<int> Source)
    {
        return new MergeSorter(Source);
    }

    public void Sort( )
    {   /* call merge sort method */   }

    //    assume the rest of ISorter is implemented
    //    as well as the main Sort( ... ) method
}
```

The `InsertionSort` and `QuickSort` classes follow the identical pattern. Of course, the SortController is completely unaware of what Sorters it is even controlling. It simply provides a list of SorterNames to whatever front end is interested. Now, my question revolves around the implementation of `ISorter.Initialize( )`. I am returning a newly instanced ISorter object with internal arrays initialized. The intention is that SortController can handle multiple requests to instance multiple sorters; additionally, the Sort method will be executed via the `SortController.StartSorter ( )` method:

```
public static void StartSorter(string SorterName, IEnumerable<int> Source)
{
    //  find ISorter by name and initialize
    //  'sorters' is an internal SorterCollection initialized from MEF discovery
    ISorter sorter = sorters.Sorters
                            .Where(key => key.Name == SorterName)
                            .FirstOrDefault( )
                            .Initialize(Source);

    if (sorter == null)
    { return; }

    SortInfo info = new SortInfo
    {
        Collection = sorter.SortedList,
        Invoker = sorter.Sort, //   delegate for asynchronous execution
        Sorter = sorter,
        Timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch( )
    };

    info.Timer.Start( );
    info.Invoker.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(SortCompleted), info);

    RunningSorters.Add(sorter);
}
```

Then in the callback you will see my one and only event defined as follows:

```
public static event EventHandler<SortCompletedEventArgs> OnSortCompleted = delegate { };

static void SortCompleted ( IAsyncResult iaResult )
{
    //  retrieve SortInfo object from IAsyncResult
    var info = (SortInfo)iaResult.AsyncState;

    //  delegate - EndInvoke
    info.Invoker.EndInvoke ( iaResult );

    //  raise event
    OnSortCompleted ( info, new SortCompletedEventArgs ( info ) );

    //  remove from running sorters list
    RunningSorters.Remove(info.Sorter);
}
```

Is this a good factory pattern for MEF? And is this a thread-safe and stable implementation capable of handling multiple sorters (say, up to 100,000 integers per sorter)?

**Edit**
Note: MergeSorter requires the original array to be split into 2 arrays; therefore `leftArray` and `rightArray`. Once the array is assigned then we are done with `Source` and it should be free to change.
The 3 sorting algorithms I used were demonstrative libraries - not my own. My own sorting routine would use the `Compare` method.
Since this is an extensible SortController employing MEF, all of the sort algorithms have public, parameterless constructors to satisfy instantiation requirement.

Comment: Shouldn't MergeSorter.Initialize() be static?

Comment: @Charles: Initialize is defined by `ISorter` so it cannot be static. Most implementations of a `Create` or `Initialize` nature would be static; the `SortController.StartSorter()` is stateless and serves as the `static` accessible initializer. Does that make sense? :)

Comment: No, I don't understand. Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me that you can't create an instance of MergeSorter. It has no public constructor and you can't call Initialize() because it's not static.

Comment: @Charles: The instantiation of MergeSorter is carried out by MEF when it discovers a class inheriting ISorter. In this case, MergeSorter and the others are 3 separate libraries (assemblies) which are passed to the `ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionContainer` and instantiated in a collection declared as `IEnumerable<ISorter> sorters`.

Comment: I see (kinda). Seems bizarre to me, but I know nothing of MEF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, Factory assumes you are to return an instance of a type. I am not too sure this is what the code actually does. I might be wrong, so please correct my logic.

1) Factory interface shall be *simple*, and only responsible for *creation*, the name of `ISorter` doesn't suggest it is a factory

2) `ISorter Initialize(IEnumerable<int> Source)`; I would argue that a method that returns an instance of the current interface is not the best practice, you face some kind of infinite recursion here

3) `IEnumerable<int> SortedList { get; }` the name suggests it is a sorted list, which is actually a [type name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) in .NET. Such code may confuse other developers

4) `MergeSorter > constructor` contains two copies of the array - you need twice as much memory for one array, which doubles the memory consumption (is this actually required for this sort algorithm?)

5) It is not thread safe, as you are using ToArray() for the same array (into two private fields). There is no synchronization there, so the array may change between these two calls, leading to nasty exceptions

**To sum up**

I would suggest to make:

1) A *thin and dedicated* factory interface

2) Move sorting functionality to implementing the [IComparer](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c+icomparer)

3) This requires quite a lot of refactoring, so if this code works, just add the locks where you copy/delete/modify the arrays (to make it thread safe) and remove (if possible) the duplicated copies

Comment: Ok, I can see why ISorter would not be a factory by the definitions provided - ISorter has 2 functions; initialize a new sorter object with the array to sort, and sort. I would argue that I don't need locks where the arrays are assigned; possibly, though, where I would assign a new instance of ISorter.